# Using selenium select command

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I m trying to select a pop up window which doesn't have any title and window id in selenium with PHP.

Whenever i give a some commands it goes to parent window.

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use xpath for the popup.

Generated this xpath by firebug and try to locate the same.

Execute your command with this xpaths.

Comment: I am able to do but using smaller path its failing can you help me please.

Comment: No as you are jumping to another htmal tag and body tag so you should not reduce the genrated path.